# heroku opencv4nodejs error in deployement

Tags: node.js, opencv, heroku

Error in deployment. How to solve this?

```
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366810+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: libopencv_core.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366811+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:18)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:40:8)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366814+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366814+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366814+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366814+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366815+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366815+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js:11:79)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366815+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366816+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
2020-11-08T09:30:21.366816+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

The app crashes everytime showing this error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps in order to use Open CV inside Heroku

1. Add [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to your Heroku Build packs. You can go to your app's settings page and add build packs.
2. Create a file named Aptfile and add the following libs: libsm6, libxrender1, libfontconfig1, libice6. Follow the example below:

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

Comment: It didnt work, giving me the same error. 

I wrote this code first
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku-community/apt
then I created Aptfile and added those libs. 

Still it is giving me same error